# Which versions of TeX do I need?

Tags: texlive, texshop, bibdesk, latexit

I currently have all of the following installed on my mac. I want to get back into using TeX for some math papers but think I have some redundant installations of engines (is that what i have below?) In any case, which can I remove and which should I keep to just be able to use latex from vscode's latex-preview?

[image: current installed]

Comment: All of those are tools related to latex but none is latex it self. If you don't know what they are? it might be better to leave them be

Comment: so i still need to install a latex engine? is there one that's easy to setup that you recommend for math?

Comment: Unless you installed TeXShop manually I assume you already have a latex on your mac. Otherwise tug.org/mactex is the easiest to install on a mac. Remember to update it after installation.

Comment: The TeXLive Utility facilitates updating your MacTeX distribution. Do you know when you last updated your TeX distribution?

Comment: 2018 was the last time I did anything latex-related and I don't remember what I did back then :(

I just updated everything above now though

Comment: I was able to get it to work into vscode (with LaTeX Workshop Extension which i think uses texlive) but I'm not sure which i can uninstall — can i uninstall the others?

Comment: These are apps that use TeX in some way. TeXShop is an editor/IDE, BibDesk is a great app for managing a bib file and all of your PDFs. LaTeXjt is a handy equation editor for creating things to insert into PowerPoint or Keynote. TeXLive utility manages the distribution. I wouldn’t delete any of them.

Comment: ah so none of them are redundant or do the same things? if so, i can accept that answer if you answer below! thanks!

Comment: Since you last installed in 2018 you might want to consider downloading the 2020 version of MacTeX however.

Comment: You have just removed the images from the question which makes it completely unintelligible.

Comment: Sorry I mean to only remove the bottom one, thank you Alan!

Comment: "engines" is ambiguous in your question. In one sense, the term might mean the executable `latex` or `xelatex` command, which is automatically made available as part of TeXLive when you install MacTeX. In a second sense, it refers to one of the scripts provided with TeXShop, such as `latex`, `xelatex`, `pdflatexmk`, etc., which govern which typesetting command is used when you click TeXShop's "Typeset" button as well as whether and which additional commands (e.g., multiple runs of `latex` to resolve references, `bibtex`, `makeindex`) are automatically executed by TeXShop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install a full MacTeX installation, a  number of very useful GUI programs are also installed.  They take up very little space, so it's not very worthwhile to delete them anyway, but mainly you may find them useful.

#### What's installed

- **TeXShop** This is a full featured TeX editor/IDE. If you've never used LaTeX before it can make your life substantially easier, since as an IDE it has most of the functions that you would want to use built in and accessible. It's not just for beginners either; I use it as my regular editor for TeX even though I use other editors for editing code.  This is actively maintained, and has a large user base.
- **BibDesk** This is a fantastic bibliography management tool. It not only allows you to maintain a `.bib` file, but also allows you to link your PDFs of the articles or notes to the `.bib` entry. It has many great features (e.g. paste a DOI and it retrieves the `.bib` data).  It also links with TeXShop so that you can type a citation key and use autocomplete to complete the citation key from your open `.bib` file.  This is also actively maintained and has a large user base.
- **TeXLive Utility**  This is a GUI interface to `tlmgr` which is used to keep your packages up to date.  It can also set other global parameters such as default page size, and allows you to switch between different installed versions of TeXLive. Many of us keep multiple years on our machines, and TeXLive Utility makes switching between them when needed simple.  One thing to note is that it assumes the most recent TeXLive distribution for updating, so it's probably a good idea to install the most recent MacTeX distribution rather than the one you currently have installed.
- **LaTeXit** This is an equation editor, designed for turning snippets of LaTeX code into various formats (PDF, PNG, SVG, TIFF, JPG, MathML) that can be inserted into other kinds of documents, such as PowerPoint or Keynote.  If you prefer to use these programs for presentations this can be a very useful tool.

Comment: thanks this was exactly what i needed!